# PHP Select Dropdown filters next dropdown via mysql

Tags: php, mysql, dropdown

Two tables...Team and Player.  Once a Team is selected via MYSQL, the Player dropdown should only show those players who have a TeamID in the Player table.  I'm not sure how to "refresh/filter" the player dropdown once a Team selection is made.

```
<td colspan="2">
<!--Teams should display from the Team table-->
<select name="myselectboxteams"> 
<option hidden selected>Select a team...</option>
<?php
    $sqlteams = "SELECT TeamName, TeamID FROM Team ORDER BY TeamName";
    $result = mysqli_query($link, $sqlteams);
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        $teamid = $row["TeamID"];
        $teamname = $row["TeamName"];
        echo "<option value=\"{$teamid}\">{$teamname}</option>";
    }
?>
</select>    
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><label for="PlayerID">Player ID:</label>
<td>
<!--Teams should display from the Player table-->
<select name="myselectboxplayer"> 
<option hidden selected>Select a player...</option>
<?php
    $sqlplayer = "SELECT PlayerID, FirstName, LastName, TeamID FROM Player ORDER BY PlayerID";
    $result = mysqli_query($link, $sqlplayer);
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        $playerid = $row["PlayerID"];
        $playerfirstname = $row["FirstName"];
        $playerlastname = $row["LastName"];
        echo "<option value=\"{$playerid}\">{$playerfirstname} {$playerlastname} </option>";
    }
?>
</select>    
</td>
```

Comment: Such things are usually done with Ajax. I recommend you to learn Ajax.

Comment: An alternative to an ajax call would be to load ALL the names into the player dropdown, but add classes to each player indicating what team they were on.  Upon selection of the team, javascript would filter by class and show the appropriate players while hiding the rest.  Whether or not you employ that method or use an ajax call, you have to use javascript, not PHP.  Any PHP solution is applied before the page is rendered to the user.  If you want things to happen after the user gets the page, you need javascript.